# Verifying behaviour of featurep when checking if a package is installed

Tags: init-file

```
;; Install package.el for package management
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)


(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

;;(when (not package-archive-contents)
;;   (package-refresh-contents))

;; Bootstrap use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

;; (package-install 'use-package)
(featurep 'use-package)
```

Hi I'm new to emacs and I'm learning how to configure the init file. I have this code above so far that I'm not sure is working. Of particular interest is the bootstrapping of use-package. It might be ok and I just don't know how to use featurep or misunderstand it's use.

So I want to verify that the packages are being installed so I read somewhere on the internet that you can use (featurep 'some-package) to verify that the package is installed. So when I run the last line of this code, it is supposed to verify that the use-package bootstrapping worked. 
I thought I should be expecting t as the output but I'm getting nil as the output from running (featurep use-package)

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome.  Can you provide a link to where you found this code?

Comment: I got that code from about 4 different sources. it's my experimentation trying to learn this stuff. @AndrewSwann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the correct behavior that (featurep 'use-package) returns nil, since even though the package is installed it is not loaded in the environment.

features variable in emacs is a list of all components provided by emacs packages. These are declared by the provide function and are checked with the require function. With M-x describe-variable (C-h v) you can see the list.

Either way you don't need to check with featurep for a feature, here a simple (require 'use-package) checks if use-package is loaded and if not loads it and puts the symbol to the features list.

Comment: Oh yeah ok, so what is the difference between "installed" and "loaded"?

Comment: installed means the file of the libraries are there, loaded means they are interpreted by the emacs lisp environment and therefore added and ready to use.

Comment: I see so package-install only installs a package and so it may not show up in featurep variable. it's only after a package is loaded that it will show up in featurep. That's what Im understanding from what you're saying @D.Dimakakos. also, I found that when i use use-package to install other packages that they actually show up in the featurep variable. This tells me that use-package installs and loads. is this correct?

Comment: that's the use of use-package! it loads packages, if you want to also check and install you use the :ensure keyword

Comment: That's awesome. Thankyou @D. Dimakakos

Comment: Glad I could help, I would like to add something more though. There is a kind of autoload system, check [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html). If you check the use-package-core.el file and find the use-package function you can see that it has ;;;###autoload before the definition. That means that if you call  the use-package function it will run even if you haven't loaded the use-package feature.

Comment: So are you saying I didn't even have to bootstrap use-package to use it? @D. Dimakakos

Comment: Ok I have read that link about autoload. Thanks. I got so much to learn.

Comment: @Drew do you think it would be beneficial to edit my answer so it reflects better the difference between installing and loading and the use of featurep and package-installed-p?

Comment: I might have accepted a little early such that others didn't get a chance to give "Any advice?" But D. Dimakakos did answer the question. @Drew if you read the post, there is one question there. "Any advice?" Did D. Dimakakos give advice regarding this issue? It cannot be disputed that he answered the question.